# CMake and Nuget packages in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, nuget

I have a project with mixed C++ and C# projects, where the C++is doing the heavy lifting, and C# provides an interface to the exterior.
In order to be able to switch between C++ compilers, we moved the solution to CMake. 
The C++ part works, but the C#, which has dependency on google protobuffer, its acting up.
This is the smallest example I was able to produce: the Cmake code

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
add_library(
    MyCSProject
    SHARED
    Test.cs
)

set_target_properties(SEM.Maeve PROPERTIES  VS_PACKAGE_REFERENCES "Google.Protobuf_3.11.4;Grpc.Tools_2.25.0;MathNet.Numerics_4.8.0-beta01"
                                        DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.5" 
                                        )
add_dependencies(MyCSProjectMyProjectWrapperCpp) # MyProjectWrapperCpp is generated before
target_compile_options(MyCSProject PUBLIC "/unsafe" "/langversion:7")
```

where Test.cs is simply:

```
using System;
using Google.Protobuf.Collections;

namespace Test
{
    public struct Test
    {
      public  RepeatedField<int> data;
    }
}
```

The generated compilation in VS (using the latest 16.6.0 version, and VisualStudio 19 as generator) is

```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe+ /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x64 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\x64\RelWithDebInfo\MyProject.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output /langversion:7.3 C:\sw_source\MyProject\src\MyProject\Test.cs "obj\x64\RelWithDebInfo\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```

There is no trace of Protobuf being passed to the compiler, and unsurprisingly the code returns error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)        2   
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RepeatedField<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   8
```

What am I missing to make it link against protobuf? If I open the generated solution it compiles fine, as the csporj file contains, as expected:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.11.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.25.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MathNet.Numerics" Version="4.8.0-beta01" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Nonetheless, I would like to make it compile from the same VS instance where I am doing the development. 
EDIT: The error seems to be random: on some rebuild the packages are linked correctly, I will report as a bug to Microsoft

Comment: I don't see a call to the `project()` command in your code to enable the C# language (such as `project(MyProject LANGUAGES CSharp)`) but I'll assume you have this elsewhere in your CMake code. I received the same error **initially** upon opening Visual Studio to build this example. However, when trying to build it a second time, it appears Nuget had done its work, and incorporated the Google.Protobuf reference and the error was gone.

Comment: Yes this is a in a directory, which is added via add_subdirectory

Comment: If you build the project again, after the initial error, does the error persist?

Comment: Yes it does. I will try to make a clean installation of VS

Comment: It seems to be random. After a while, the nuget package seems to be added. Then if I clean up the project and compile again, the problem returns

Comment: This could be a CMake/VS bug, in which package references are not immediately applied. It seems that the first build attempt in VS consistently yields the missing assembly reference error, but the second build attempt builds OK.

Comment: why don't generate csproj from CMake a use dotnet/cli ?
e.g. https://github.com/Mizux/dotnet-native